# php + JS button value save

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Logic is that , on click div.buttons gonna hide and get second form : save date to mysql .. problem is in this : 1) i have to save grab name or value from buttons  : problem no refresh page . i tried send date to php with ajax , with GET or POST methodes from js .. buttons are taken mysql and echoed in php like this : 
PHP: `foreach ($res as $row) {
            echo '<tr><td><button id="pupShow" name="'.$row["ID"].'">'.$row["SubjectName"].'</button> </td></tr>';
       }`  
 
 JS:
`$("button#pupShow").click(function () {
       $("div.pupInput").show("slow");
        $("div.showMarks").toggle("slow");
        $("div.lessons").toggle("slow");
        alert(this.name);
       // $GLOBALS['myglob'] = this.name;
       // window.location.href ="subID.php?subID="+this.name;
        // return false;` 
this is js were i handle click on button 
 any help ?

i got eye on transforming first buttons into selected manue . so i could grab them by name from php , but its destroy my visual ..

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand, can you please rephrase it more clearly?

Comment: @nullability : i have to save in JS value or name from clicked Button , and then and when form is submits , i need this var in my action.php file .. to explain : those buttons are "Subjects in school" , so i select subject by clicking , and it shows up second hiden form for marks ... i found just one way, change my subject echo intyo dropdown select manue ...

Comment: @laura it refreshed . i cant refresh page , on button click i hid this div and show up second hiden div... so on refresh it returns me back to start ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to reload the page, then you can try:

```
foreach ($res as $row) {
        echo '<tr><td><button id="pupShow" name="'.$row["ID"].'" onclick="return false;">'.$row["SubjectName"].'</button> </td></tr>';
   }
```

or

```
$("button#pupShow").click(function (el) {
   el.preventDefault();

   var data = 'nume=' + el.val()

   $.ajax({
       url: "subID.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: data,
       cache: false,
       success: function (html) {
           if (html) {
               // animations here
               alert('Success! Form submitted');
           } else{
               alert('Error! Please try again');
           }
       }
   });
```

I didn't test it but it should help you understand how the function will look like.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to submit some data without refreshing the page? Since you're using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$.post("test.php", {name: "Mathematics"}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("Response loaded: " + data);
});
```